# Is there an alternative way to get rid of ros log files?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting the error

```
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/home/an/.ros/log] is over 1GB. 
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.
```

Well i can rosclean purge and delete all everything or maybe delete using. Is there a way to delete the oldest entries and lighten my log files. It would not be ideal to clean the entire log file.

Also I wonder what happens if I let it accumulate and not clean? I am asking this question without much googling. So excuse me if there is already something clearly written. ROS insights are most welcome. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258978/is-there-an-alternative-way-to-get-rid-of-ros-log-files?/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Also I wonder what happens if I let it accumulate and not clean?

Well, you run out of disk space, eventually...

You not googling is obvious, as your question directly relates to http://answers.ros.org/question/229966/does-ros-have-rolling-log-files-ability-to-limit-total-size/ :-)

About your question though:

Of course. However, this requires some manual scripting. IMO, there are two ways.

1. Write a simple script that you start via `cron`. You can e.g. use the `find` tool with the `-mtime` property to get the last modified time of a file and delete via this.
2. Use `logrotate`. However, as the log files typically get "stamped" with the RUN_ID, this will probably also need some fiddeling with the `prerotate` and `postrotate` scripts.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-04-11**:
Thanks a lot @mig